# After scaled video, it convert transparent background to white

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, video-editing

I scaled video using ffmpeg. When i scaled video, the output video having white background ,while the input video having transparent background.
below command using for scaled video.

ffmpeg -i inputVideo.mp4 -vf scale=100:100 outputVideo.mp4

you can see the image below that is take from my video,for more understanding my problem.

image from input video
[image]

you can see the above image from input video having no white background.

image from output video
[image]

you can see the above image from output video having white backgournd.

please give me your valuable answer regarding this question.
any answer will be very appreciate.`D: onProgress:   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
D: onProgress:   libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
D: onProgress:   libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
D: onProgress:   libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
D: onProgress:   libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
D: onProgress:   libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
D: onProgress:   libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
D: onProgress:   libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
D: onProgress:   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
D: onProgress: Input #0, gif, from '/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/eye.gif':
D: onProgress:   Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
D: onProgress:     Stream #0:0: Video: gif, bgra, 480x190, 5 fps, 10 tbr, 100 tbn, 100 tbc
D: onProgress: Output #0, gif, to '/storage/emulated/0/GIF/REV20170308_101145.gif':
D: onProgress:   Metadata:
D: onProgress:     encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
D: onProgress:     Stream #0:0: Video: gif, bgr8, 125x56, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 10 fps, 100 tbn, 10 tbc
D: onProgress:     Metadata:
D: onProgress:       encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 gif
D: onProgress: Stream mapping:
D: onProgress:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (gif (native) -> gif (native))
D: onProgress: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
D: onProgress: frame=   11 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=      17kB time=00:00:02.90 bitrate=  48.8kbits/s speed=14.8x

D: onProgress: video:16kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 5.287261%
D: Started command : ffmpeg [Ljava.lang.String;@422f62d0
D: onSuccess: ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
     built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
     configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
     libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
     libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
     libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
     libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
     libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
     libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
     libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
     libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
   Input #0, gif, from '/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/eye.gif':
     Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
       Stream #0:0: Video: gif, bgra, 480x190, 5 fps, 10 tbr, 100 tbn, 100 tbc
   Output #0, gif, to '/storage/emulated/0/GIF/REV20170308_101145.gif':
     Metadata:
       encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
       Stream #0:0: Video: gif, bgr8, 125x56, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 10 fps, 100 tbn, 10 tbc
       Metadata:
         encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 gif
   Stream mapping:
     Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (gif (native) -> gif (native))
   Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
   frame=   11 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=      17kB time=00:00:02.90 bitrate=  48.8kbits/s speed=14.8x

   video:16kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 5.287261%`

Comment: Show full console output.

Comment: i am using ffmpeg lib in android.

Comment: show you the logcat?

Comment: see the edit question

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-gifflags transdiff`, so

```
ffmpeg -i in.gif -gifflags transdiff out.gif
```

You'll have to add in all other filters & parameters you need.

Comment: Can you share your GIF?